# VBA LOOP Creating same titles on all worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put the same on row 1 across all worksheets. How would I create a loop to do this? I am pretty new to VBA. I recorded a macro but its still very long. 18 worksheets need to have this. Here is what the recorded macro looks like.

```
Sheets("C3 MBEL TET OPIS_CMA").Select
Range("F1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSTRIK"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PRECID"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PEXCH"
Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PQTY"
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PCTYM"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PFC"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PACCT"
Range("K1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PPRTCP"
Range("E1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSUBTY"
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PSBUS"
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PBS"
```

Of course, this is repeated 17 more times except with different worksheet names.

Comment: I recommend to read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @Emalee Does your code work as is?

Comment: @ashleedawg yes it does!

Comment: @ashleedawg yes they are just named ranges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array to store the sheet names you want to write the headers, and then loop through that array to write it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteHeaderIntoSheets()
    Dim WorksheetNames As Variant
    WorksheetNames = Array("C3 MBEL TET OPIS_CMA", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3") 'your sheet names

    Dim ws As Variant
    For Each ws In WorksheetNames 
        With Worksheets(ws)
            .Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSTRIK"
            .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "PRECID"
            .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "PEXCH"
            .Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "PQTY"
            .Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "PCTYM"
            .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "PFC"
            .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "PACCT"
            .Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "PPRTCP"
            .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSUBTY"
            .Range("H1").FormulaR1C1 = "PSBUS"
            .Range("I1").FormulaR1C1 = "PBS"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively you can also use an array for the header row which makes it even faster.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteHeaderIntoSheets()
    Dim WorksheetNames As Variant
    WorksheetNames = Array("C3 MBEL TET OPIS_CMA", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3") 'your sheet names

    Dim HeaderRow As Variant 'your header values
    HeaderRow = Array("PRECID", "PACCT", "PEXCH", "PFC", "PSUBTY", "PSTRIK", "PCTYM", "PSBUS", "PBS", "PQTY", "PPRTCP")

    Dim ws As Variant
    For Each ws In WorksheetNames
        Worksheets(ws).Range("A1").Resize(ColumnSize:=1 + UBound(HeaderRow)).Value = HeaderRow
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: just beat me to it +

Comment: Was about to write something similar, but I like your way with going for "For Each ws In Worksheetnames"

Comment: Added an alternative using an array for the header row too, which makes it even faster.

Comment: I was trying a variation of this where you wouldn't have to loop through the sheets - manually you'd select the relevant sheets while holding `Ctrl` and enter the formula.  Seems like in VBA the sheets and ranges would still need selecting otherwise you get an `Object doesn't support this property or method` even though `Worksheets(WorksheetNames)` is an array of worksheet objects.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Yes, accessing ranges in multiple worksheets at once is not supported. So no shortcut for the loop here.